# Set an HTML class to host in an Angular directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, classname, angular2-hostbinding

How would you do to add and set an HTML class that can be changed with a parameter, with an Angular directive  ?
Let's say we have a div with an already existing class, but no directive :

```
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Now, we want to attach a directive to it, and one parameter :

```
<div directiveName set="X" class="myClass myClass-X"></div>
```

If I need a 4, then my class added dynamically would be changed like that :

```
<div directiveName set="4" class="myClass myClass-4"></div>
```

I totally know how to add a class with @hostbinding, but I can't find how to change this one dynamically with my "set" parameter

Thank you very much

Comment: Really not sure what you are asking here... https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass. Have you looked at ngClass for assigning conditions to style html?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean. Do you want to add a class based on the value passed into the set attribute from inside the directive?

Comment: @Keff Exactly !
Like in Javascript: element.classList.add("myclass-" + set), but from inside the directive. So that when no directive is present, there is no need for this class or ngClass

Comment: I would suggest reading this post https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives it explains how to get access to an ElementRef, then you can just use it as in Vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this might be accomplished as follows:

I did this from memory, maybe something is not working as expected but I think you get the gist of it.

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[directiveName]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
       
       // Check if element has the 'set' directive.
       if('set' in el.nativeElement.attributes){
         // Get the "set" attribute.
         const setAttribute = el.nativeElement.getAttribute('set');

         // Add the class to the element.
         el.nativeElement.classList.add(setAttribute);
       }
    }
}
```

"You use the **ElementRef** in the directive's constructor to inject a reference to the host DOM element, the element to which you applied 'directiveName'."

I would suggest checking [this](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) page out, it explains in quite a bit of detail how directives work.

Comment: Ow ! thank you sir ! So easier to do this like that, for me !